# Extracting Subvector from Vector Register in LLVM IR

Tags: vector, llvm, simd, llvm-ir

I am looking for a more compact way to extract a consecutive `<4 x float>` (e.g., `xmm0`) out of a `<8 x float>` (e.g., `ymm0`) register, which will ultimately use the SIMD vector width naming.

This is working as expected, but rather elaborate:

```
%out.1 = extractelement <8 x float> %out.0, i32 0
%out.2 = extractelement <8 x float> %out.0, i32 1
%out.3 = extractelement <8 x float> %out.0, i32 2
%out.4 = extractelement <8 x float> %out.0, i32 3
%out.5 = insertelement <4 x float> undef, float %out.1, i32 0
%out.6 = insertelement <4 x float> %out.5, float %out.2, i32 1
%out.7 = insertelement <4 x float> %out.6, float %out.3, i32 2
%out.8 = insertelement <4 x float> %out.7, float %out.4, i32 3
```

Is there a leaner way to accomplish the same?

Comment: Is it always the high 4 (`vextractf128`) or the low 4 (just a reinterpret)?  Or do you sometimes want elements 2..5 or something, and want LLVM to optimize to a `vpermpd ymm, ymm, imm` to create the result you want in an xmm?  (or a `vpermps` with a vector control for elements 1..4 or 3..6.)  I don't actually know LLVM-IR well, but if it can express any of those x86 shuffle instructions in one LLVM-IR instruction, use that.

Comment: It will always be the high or low part, no shuffles required just a different register name. But using a shuffle in the IR might be an option if LLVM replaces it with a register name change. I will try that and report back.

Comment: @PeterCordes That was the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Extracting the high 128 does require a shuffle in x86 asm, e.g. `vextractf128`.  It's not like ARM32 where the high and low halves of `q10` alias to `d21` and `d20` which can be accessed directly.  Only the low half of a YMM is aliased by an XMM reg.  But anyway, sure like in your answer you can write it as a shuffle with a separate index for each element, and LLVM will compile it to an extract, or nothing, or to a `vpermps` if you use different indices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shufflevector` will accomplish the same as above (provided you are only interest in `%out.8`) and LLVM will replace it with a simple register name change (e.g., if `%out.1` is `ymm0`, `%out.8` would be `xmm0`).

Single line to replace eight:

```
%out.8 = shufflevector <8 x float> %out.0, <8 x float> undef, <4 x i32> <i32 0, i32 1, i32 2, i32 3>
```